# Remote XA JMS Connection

Tags: java, jboss, jms, xa

Is it possible to provide and lookup connection factories that are transactional on a JBoss AS 7? The standard "RemoteConnectionFactory" doesn't seem to be transactional (XA) and I don't know how to make it XA or how to define some sort of XARemoteConnectionFactory that I can use from a remote client.

I tried adding the `<xa>true</xa>` element (which works in a hornetq configuration but is illegal in a jboss config file) and tried to create a `<pooled-connection-factory>` like the "java:/jmsXA" (but I wasn't able to look it up in the context even with a correct name for exporting).